# How does Visual Studio decide which port to run applications on?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When you run an application from within visual studio, it seems to pick a random port on localhost.  For example, running an application right now, I get

> http://localhost:3240/ApplicationStuffHere

I realize this port gets loaded into the solution file, via

> VWDPort = "3240"

How does this get decided on?  it seems fairly random.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, ASP.NET Web Application Projects are configured to launch and run using the built-in VS Web Server (aka Cassini) on a random HTTP port on the machine.

This port number can be changed if this port is already in use, or if you want to specifically test and run using a different number:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/HelloWorld/step7.PNG))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little bit old, but I was wondering the same thing. I eventually found the answer for VS2005, but figured I'd share it with the stack overflow community.

1. Open your project
2. Click (not right click) on the name of the  project in the solution explorer (that top, bolded line)
3. Hit f4 - this will bring up a properties panel
4. Change "Use dynamic ports" to False
5. Optionally change the Port number to whatever port you want to use

And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

This port number is initially assigned randomly, but Visual Studio will try to use that same port number every time the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Properties of your web application in solution explorer (Right click > Properties)

The web tab is the one you are looking for.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Web tab?  Right click -> Properties yields a sidebar with Common Properties and Configuration Properties.  No web tab.  This is VS2005, should have specified.

Comment: Ah ... I am looking at 2008, sorry

Comment: Is your project a web application?

Comment: Yes it is.  I am right clicking on the solution itself in the solution explorer, yes?

Comment: No actually on the project inside the solution, sir :)